# How to use the Moon Trek API to make grayscale heightmaps?

Tags: terrain, heightmap

I have a game project where the player will explore the moon's surface.

For the terrain I thought I could use this particular [image height-map,](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4720) but it is so massive that my computer can not handle it. Then I found this NASA site [NASA MOON TREK](https://trek.nasa.gov/moon/) which also has an API to get images of the moon's surface on a scaled level. However, [this API documentation](https://trek.nasa.gov/tiles/apidoc/trekAPI.html?body=moon) is the worst I have ever worked with.

Can anyone help me find these height-maps so that I can complete my project?

Comment: You may find that GIS folks know more about how to work with open map APIs than most game developers do, so you might want to consider asking this on the GIS StackExchange instead. [They have a whole tag devoted to working with WMTS data sources](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wmts).

Comment: thanks a  lot @DMGregory

Comment: Too bad that the resolution of that data is just ~50m per pixel. Not nearly enough for interesting first person exploration. In order to use that data in  a game, the game would either need to play from birds-eye perspective or you would need to use procedural generation to fill in the details.